# Facebook Image does not show up on Feed

Tags: facebook, addthis

I have plugin or module I'm currently using to share articles on social media called `Addthis`. I'm trying to figure out why the image does not show up in the feed but in the preview it display the image before posting

Here is a screenshot of the issue

[image]

Before posting on Facebook the image shows up on the preview as seen in the screenshot below

[image]

I even tried using Facebook Debug and it shows the image

[image]